# Change color background slide white gradient IONIC 3

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I would like to change the orange background to green, but with some animation, for example, when it is orange it will turn green.

If you can check out the two gifs I've assembled, you'll understand what I mean.

***HOW IT IS CURRENTLY*** -> [GIF](https://gyazo.com/049733f9e765fb01547e0845cc994f4e)

***HOW I WANT THEM TO BE*** -> [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsEf4.jpg)

**HOME.HTML**

```
<ion-content >
  <div  style="background-color: #f87f0e; padding: 10px;">
    <ion-slides pager>
      <ion-slide >
        <ion-card style="border-radius: 15px;margin-bottom: 35px">
          <ion-card-content style="font-family: sans-serif;">
            <ion-row>
              <ion-col col-12>
                <P style="color: #9e9e9e;float: left;font-size: 15px">BALANCE PERSONAL</P>
              </ion-col>
              <ion-col col-12>
                <H2 style="float: left;font-size: 20px">4.235632 <small>MIC</small></H2>  
              </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <ion-card style="border-radius: 15px">
          <ion-card-content style="font-family: sans-serif;">
            <ion-row>
              <ion-col col-12>
                <P style="color: #9e9e9e;float: left;font-size: 15px">BALANCE BUSINESS</P>
              </ion-col>
              <ion-col col-12>
                <H2 style="float: left;font-size: 20px">4.235632 <small>MIC</small></H2>  
              </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change backgroud-color for each ion-card.

```
 <ion-content >
  <div  style="background-color: #f87f0e; padding: 10px;">
    <ion-slides pager>
      <ion-slide >
        <ion-card style="background-color: red; border-radius: 15px;margin-bottom: 35px">
          <ion-card-content style="font-family: sans-serif;">
            <ion-row>
              <ion-col col-12>
                <P style="color: #9e9e9e;float: left;font-size: 15px">BALANCE PERSONAL</P>
              </ion-col>
              <ion-col col-12>
                <H2 style="float: left;font-size: 20px">4.235632 <small>MIC</small></H2>  
              </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <ion-card style="background-color: green; border-radius: 15px">
          <ion-card-content style="font-family: sans-serif;">
            <ion-row>
              <ion-col col-12>
                <P style="color: #9e9e9e;float: left;font-size: 15px">BALANCE BUSINESS</P>
              </ion-col>
              <ion-col col-12>
                <H2 style="float: left;font-size: 20px">4.235632 <small>MIC</small></H2>  
              </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```